# Convert list of Tuples to Dictionary

Tags: c#

How to convert in the shortest way a list of Tuples to Dictionary (C#) ?

```
IList<Tuple<long, int>> applyOnTree = getTuples();
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Assuming the `long` is the key and the `int` is the value;

```
applyOnTree.ToDictionary(x => x.Item1, x => x.Item2);
```

Obviously, just reverse those two if it's the other way around.

Comment: That's correct, but just remember to include a "using System.Linq" directive if you don't already have it at the top of your file.

Comment: This works fine assuming that there exists one unique key for each element in the list. Otherwise, it's not clear how to do a LINQ query (an iterative conversion is quite easy).

Answer (score 5):

Use `ToDictionary` extension method:

```
var dictionary = applyOnTree.ToDictionary(l => l.Item1, l => l.Item2);
```